Strange behaviour of requiredWidthIn() inside Row in compose
I have a Row which contains three Text components. I want the second and third texts to reduce their width as needed, down to a minimum of 50 dp, when the first text is too long.
The issue I'm having is that when I set requiredWidthIn(50.dp) for second and third texts inside that row and if the first text is long, it is pushing the second text until it disappears.
The other issue is that when it pushes the other texts, it's disregarding the end and spacedBy paddings I've set. All the paddings are gone from the second and third texts.
Is there any way to fix this? thanks!

@Composable
fun MinWidthWithRowTestComp(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(color = Color.Black)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(16.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(color = Color.Red),
            text = "Hello World! Hello World!  Hello World! Hello World! ",
        )

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(color = Color.Blue)
                .requiredWidthIn(min = 50.dp),
            text = "Hello World!",
        )

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(color = Color.Yellow)
                .requiredWidthIn(min = 50.dp),
            text = "Hello World!",
        )
    }
}


This is a fine example of how Constraints and required Modifiers work in Jetpack Compose. You can refer this answer for how requiredWidth gets centered when it doesn't abide parent Constraints.

Row, also Column too in vertical orientation, measures children in a loop with Constraints.maxWidth - spaced used by other children by summing this after each measurement.
What happens is more apparent if you add some borders and offset as

@Preview
@Composable
fun MinWidthWithRowTestComp() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(color = Color.Black)
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp)
            .border(1.dp, Color.Red),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(color = Color.Red),
            text = "Hello World! Hello World!  Hello World! Hello World! ",
        )

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .border(2.dp, Color.Cyan)
                .offset(y = 40.dp)
                .background(color = Color.Blue)
                .requiredWidthIn(min = 50.dp),
            text = "Hello World!",
        )

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .border(2.dp, Color.Magenta)
                .offset(y = 60.dp)
                .background(color = Color.Yellow)
                .requiredWidthIn(min = 50.dp),
            text = "Hello World!",
        )
    }
}

Cyan border is the space left after red Text is measured but by using requiredWidth you change Constraints of Text so it gets centered. And for the last one you can see that zero space is left so it gets center at right side of the parent Row. Everything works as intended however this is not the outcome you want.
You can use Layout for the result you desire. Unlike Row you can measure second and third Texts before first one with minWidth = 50.dp.roundToPx() and measure first one with remaining space after Texts and spaces you wish to set between. I can  post sample if it's needed.
Custom Layout
Result. As you can see second and third one has min 50.dp width and if they grow first Text needs to be measured with smaller maxWidth

Implementation
@Composable
fun CustomRow(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    horizontalSpacing: Dp,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {

    val measurePolicy = remember(horizontalSpacing) {
        object : MeasurePolicy {
            override fun MeasureScope.measure(
                measurables: List<Measurable>,
                constraints: Constraints,
            ): MeasureResult {
                require(measurables.size == 3)

                val horizontalSpacingPx = horizontalSpacing.roundToPx()
                val minMeasurementWidth = 50.dp.roundToPx()

            
                val maxWidthForSecondOrThirdText =
                    ( constraints.maxWidth - 2 * horizontalSpacingPx - minMeasurementWidth).
                            coerceAtLeast(minMeasurementWidth)

                // Measure second and third placeables  with min 50.dp
                // and with max that each one of them can only grow total width - spaces -50.dp
                val textPlaceables: List<Placeable> = measurables
                    .filterIndexed { index, _ ->
                        index != 0
                    }
                    .map { measurable ->
                        measurable.measure(
                            constraints.copy(
                                minWidth = minMeasurementWidth,
                                maxWidth = maxWidthForSecondOrThirdText
                            )
                        )
                    }

                // This is available space after second and third text and 32.dp spacing between
                val availableWidthForFirstText =
                    constraints.maxWidth - 2 * horizontalSpacingPx - textPlaceables.sumOf { it.width }

                val firstTextPlaceable = measurables.first().measure(
                    constraints.copy(
                        minWidth = 0,
                        maxWidth = availableWidthForFirstText.coerceAtLeast(0)
                    )
                )

                // This works with Modifier.fillMaxWidth or Modifier.width() is used
                // And simplicity
                val layoutWidth = constraints.maxWidth

                // Layout height is the maximum of three
                val layoutHeight = firstTextPlaceable.height.coerceAtLeast(
                    textPlaceables.maxOf { it.height }
                )

                var posX: Int

                return layout(layoutWidth, layoutHeight) {
                    firstTextPlaceable.placeRelative(0, 0)
                    posX = firstTextPlaceable.width

                    textPlaceables.forEachIndexed { index, placeable ->
                        val space = horizontalSpacingPx * (index + 1)
                        placeable.placeRelative(posX + space, 0)
                        posX += placeable.width

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Layout(
        modifier = modifier,
        content = content,
        measurePolicy = measurePolicy
    )
}

Demo and Usage
@Preview
@Composable
fun CustomRowTest() {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {

        var text1 by remember {
            mutableStateOf("Hello World! Hello World!  Hello World! Hello World! ")
        }

        var text2 by remember {
            mutableStateOf("Hello World!")
        }

        var text3 by remember {
            mutableStateOf("Hello World!")
        }

        TextField(value = text1, onValueChange = {text1 = it})
        TextField(value = text2, onValueChange = {text2 = it})
        TextField(value = text3, onValueChange = {text3 = it})

        CustomRow(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().border(2.dp, Color.Green),
            horizontalSpacing = 16.dp
        ) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(color = Color.Red),
                text = text1,
            )

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(color = Color.Blue),
                text = text2,
            )

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(color = Color.Yellow),
                text = text3,
            )
        }
    }
}

Custom Layout2
This one measures first Text with available space which can shrink second on third down to 50.dp minimum.
@Composable
fun CustomRow(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    horizontalSpacing: Dp,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {

    val measurePolicy = remember(horizontalSpacing) {
        object : MeasurePolicy {
            override fun MeasureScope.measure(
                measurables: List<Measurable>,
                constraints: Constraints,
            ): MeasureResult {
                require(measurables.size == 3)

                val horizontalSpacingPx = horizontalSpacing.roundToPx()
                val minMeasurementWidth = 50.dp.roundToPx()
                val availableWidth = constraints.maxWidth - 2 * horizontalSpacingPx

                // This is available space after 32.dp spacing between
                val availableWidthForFirstText = availableWidth - 2 * minMeasurementWidth

                val firstTextPlaceable = measurables.first().measure(
                    constraints.copy(
                        minWidth = 0,
                        maxWidth = availableWidthForFirstText.coerceAtLeast(0)
                    )
                )

                var unusedWidth =
                    (availableWidth - minMeasurementWidth - firstTextPlaceable.width)
                        .coerceAtLeast(minMeasurementWidth)


                // Measure second and third placeables  with min 50.dp

                val textPlaceables: List<Placeable> = measurables
                    .filterIndexed { index, _ ->
                        index != 0
                    }
                    .map { measurable ->
                        measurable.measure(
                            constraints.copy(
                                minWidth = minMeasurementWidth,
                                maxWidth = unusedWidth
                            )
                        ).also {
                            unusedWidth =
                                (unusedWidth - it.width).coerceAtLeast(minMeasurementWidth)
                        }
                    }


                // This works with Modifier.fillMaxWidth or Modifier.width() is used
                // And simplicity
                val layoutWidth = constraints.maxWidth

                // Layout height is the maximum of three
                val layoutHeight = firstTextPlaceable.height.coerceAtLeast(
                    textPlaceables.maxOf { it.height }
                )

                var posX: Int

                return layout(layoutWidth, layoutHeight) {
                    firstTextPlaceable.placeRelative(0, 0)
                    posX = firstTextPlaceable.width

                    textPlaceables.forEachIndexed { index, placeable ->
                        val space = horizontalSpacingPx * (index + 1)
                        placeable.placeRelative(posX + space, 0)
                        posX += placeable.width

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Layout(
        modifier = modifier,
        content = content,
        measurePolicy = measurePolicy
    )
}


Can you post your sample code ? Thanks in advance!

Added implementation and demo for creating a custom Row with your specifications i guess.

Thanks Thracian. Actually the behaviour I was looking for is to shrink the second and third text gradually to their min width when the first text is getting longer.

If that's the case measure first Text with maxWidth - horizontalSpace *2 - 50.dp.toPx()*2 and measure second and third with remaining space after first Text and 2 * horizontalSpace. If you understand how Layout works it's not that hard to do these changes.

@Thracian Is is always stunning for me how you can come up with these kinds of answers. May I ask how much years of experience you already have with Jetpack Compose?

@BenjyTec thanks. I have been using it almost 4 years i guess, probably started with one of the alpha versions, can't recall. I had started few months before the date of tutorial i have. I had started it twice though, deleted first one. At the time, they kept changing names, etc. and i was having lots of compile errors, so i restarted. I also asked lots of questions myself, and read source code of Composables and Modifiers.
